# Object reference not set to an instance while not being null

Tags: c#

I'm getting some unexpected behavior in my process. I'm doing the following.

```
IEnumerable<Thing> things = ...;
IEnumerable<Thing> subset = things.Where(a => a.SomeFlag);
String info = "null: " + (subset == null);
```

The above works and *info* tells me that the object isn't *null*. So I wish to check the number of the elements in *subset* by this.

```
IEnumerable<Thing> things = ...;
IEnumerable<Thing> subset = things.Where(a => a.SomeFlag);
String info = "null: " + (subset == null);
String count = subset.Count();
```

Now I get an exception giving me the error message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What do I miss?!

Comment: Some Thing might be null.

Comment: @tia So? I'm executing *Count* on the *IEnumerable*, not the objects in it.

Comment: It means that at least one of the elements in `things` is null. You can count null elements just fine, but you can't access `.SomeFlag` on them. And you can't enumerate all the elements in `subset` (to count them) without accessing `.SomeFlag` on all the elements of `things`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An `IEnumerable<Thing>` implies deferred execution.

In your first fragment `subset` and `things` are never enumerated.

In the second fragment, it is the call to `Count()` that enumerates the lists and only then it comes to light that one of the  `a` is null in `a => a.SomeFlag`.

Comment: Actually, I call *Count* on *things* and it works. It's the *subset* that crashes upon enumeration. Sorry, should've mention that. My bad.

Comment: That figures. `things` contains 1+ `null` values but you can still `Count()` it. But the filter for `subset` fails.

Comment: try `bool check = things.Any(a => a == null);`

Comment: Nope, sorry. I got *false*. There are no nulls in there... What do I miss?

Comment: @KonradViltersten If there are no nulls, then the `.SomeFlag` get accessor probably contains something that is causing a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Oh, du'h... I was, of course, lying all the time. The property isn't really a direct property. It's a call like *a=>a.GetSome().IsSome*. The stupid *GetSome* can be *null* because the stupid *String* is defaulted to *null*. Stupid computer... Doing stuff I'm telling it to... Instead of what I mean... (Irony here, of course!)

Answer (score 6):

It's possible that one of the `Thing`'s in `subset` is `null`. You can try this:

```
IEnumerable<Thing> subset = things.Where(a => a != null && a.SomeFlag);
```

Note that due to the way Linq's lazy evaluation, you won't get any exception you call `.Where` because all it's doing at that point is setting up a condition for filtering the elements of `things`. Only later when you call `.Count` is it actually evaluating the results.

**Update:** With the new [null-condition operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) in C# 6 (also called the safe navigation or 'Elvis' operator), we can do the same thing a bit more succinctly:

```
IEnumerable<Thing> subset = things.Where(a => a?.SomeFlag);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can see what really happens here with a bit simplified example.

`Test` class:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

And LINQ query on `IEnumerable<Test>`:

```
IEnumerable<Test> source = new List<Test>() {
    new Test { Value = 10 },
    null,
    new Test { Value = 20 }
};

IEnumerable<Test> filteredSource = source.Where(x => x.Value > 10);

// return false
Console.WriteLine(filteredSource == null);

// throws NullReferenceException
Console.WriteLine(filteredSource.Count());
```

Why does it happens? Because **`filteredSource == null` does not cause collection enumeration**, so `Where` predicate is not being fired on any `source` collection element.

However, when you call `Count()` on `filteredSource` the predicate is being called on every item from `source` collection, and when it comes to an item which is `null`: `null.Value > 10` throws the exception.

How to make it work? Extend the predicate with `x != null` check:

```
IEnumerable<Test> filteredSource = source.Where(x => x != null && x.Value > 10);
```

Comment: I understand the explanation but still don't the what the compiler's problem is. Suppose that my *IEnumerable* consists of a bunch of *null* elements. I want to know their number. Why can't I get it...

Comment: You can get number of `null` elements within collection using different predicate: `Where(x => x == null)`

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. In the *things* I got 8 instances, none of which is *null*. Then, when I filter using a condition, I get *subset*. I still don't understand why I can execute *Count* on *things* but not on the *subset*. The latter is constituted of the same (or fewer) elements than *things*. Am I slow today?

Comment: But actually you don't have a *subset* until you iterate over source collection and call predicate on every item from it. The subset is calculated when you call `Count()`: the predicate is used to determine if item should be a part of *subset* or not, and that's  why `NullReferenceException` can happen then.

Comment: I'm sorry but I just don't get it (or perhaps I explain it wrongly). I have a set from the start. I call *Count* on that set. Everything is just fine. **Then** I create a subset of the first set. It can't contain "dangerous" elements more than the newly created. Calling *Count* on the new one results in the crash. Which element (in the new set) causes the crash that hasn't caused it before (in the original set)?!

Comment: **LINQ makes all queries deferred, so your *subset* don't really exists until you call a method that cause the query execution.** You can check that by calling `subset.ToList()` - it should cause `NullReferenceException` too.

Comment: I call *Count* on the first set. Then it gets enumerated, right? **Afterwards** I create the new set. I still can't grasp where the *null* might come from. There are no *null* elements in the original set (checked with *Any(a=>a==null)*...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so suppose you had the following items in `things`:

```
Thing A  SomeFlag = true
Thing B  SomeFlag = false
null
Thing C  SomeFlag = true
```

First you count all the items in `things`. So you iterate over 4 objects, find 4 objects, and know that the result is 4. Easy.

Now you want to count all of the items in `subset` which means you need to figure out which items are in `subset` in the first place. So you go about counting them:

```
Thing A .... A.SomeFlag is true, so count it
Thing B .... B.SomeFlag is not true, so don't count it
null    .... null.SomeFlag  NULLREFERENCEEXCEPTION
```

And that's where your error comes from.

Note that even if all of the elements in things are not null, you can still get a NullReferenceException if the `.SomeFlag` get accessor has a side effect that could cause a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention that. I've checked - there are no nulls in the original set.

Comment: You missed my last line. If there are no nulls, then `.SomeFlag` must have a side-effect that is causing the exception.

Comment: +1 Yupp, correct. Kudos. However, at this point I was so frustrated that I needed a clearer formulation, like "your property is calling a method in the getter doing baaad stuff". My fault entirely. :)